# mostrar valor selecionado no listview c#

Tags: c#

Bom dia. 
Tenho um listView com uma vista em forma de lista. Queria que ao clicar numa determinada linha, me guardasse o valor seleccionado. Como posso fazer?

Comment: O que você tentou?

Comment: listView.SelectedItems.ToString();

Comment: Vários eventos, como o click ...

Comment: O meu problema é que estou a utilizar uma listview da infragistics

Comment: ela tem o evento SelectedIndexChanged ?

Comment: Não. Tem o ItemActivated; ItemSelectionChanged;

Comment: usa o ItemSelectionChanged

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se em algum momento precisar pegar o valor selecionado no *listView* utilize o seguinte codigo:

```
listView.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```

Se precisar que toda vez que o item selecionado mudar o valor seja atualizado em algum lugar utilize o evento *SelectedIndexChanged* e la pode utilizar o mesmo código de cima para pegar o valor.

**Lembre-se**
O listView tem a propriedade de multi-seleção (escolher vários itens ao mesmo tempo), certifique-se de que é isto que deseja.

Comment: ela está a usar um componente de terceiros, infragistics, mas certamente é algo parecido =]

Comment: enquanto digitava fui me certificar no código e não vi este comentário, vou editar

Comment: Já consegui. Funcionou na mesma ! :)

Comment: @RovannLinhalis se olhar o histórico de edições notara que editei a pergunta, mas a AP Conseguiu realizar da primeira forma então eu reverti a edição

Comment: Apenas fiz uma observação, pois não conheço o controle que ela está usando, e poderia ser diferente. =]

Comment: Sim, e agradeço por me informar =P

Comment: Tenho isto, como faço nesta parte, para me selecionar o item ? : if(listView.Items[j].)

Answer (score 2):

Utilizando a Infragistics, pode ser possível selecionar o item no listvew da seguinte forma:

```
string text = listView.SelectedItems[0].Text.ToString();
```